# Ford Ranger clutch pedal won't depress

Tags: ford, clutch

I just had the clutch replaced 2 months ago on my 1995 Ford Ranger.  I went to the store yesterday and when I went to leave, the clutch pedal wouldn't depress.

Answer (score 1):

Check the clutch line at the quick disconnect ([source](http://www.explorerforum.com/forums/showthread.php?t=305596)).  If it has come loose that would explain not being able to depress the pedal.